# how do I save whatsapp login session but don't want to use user-data-dir in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, session, automation, whatsapp

this is usual method to save whatsapp session, but in case of multiple user it would use lots of memory to store data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Any") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

but it takes almost 50mb to save credential for future login.
also I tried to fetch cookies by using `driver.getcookies()` though it return `[]` empty block which means **WhatsApp does not store cookies for session persistence** *already tried .pickle*
other possible option was to keep driver active but it would affect system memory and bandwidth.
Is there any alternate method to save login session?